# Extracts parts of a int before "." javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have any decimal number, for example "2.5" or "5545454454.656", How I could get the number before the dot no matter how long the number is it

Comment: basic regular expression match number with a dot...

Comment: floor? ceiling functions/

Comment: You can parse the value to int using parseInt() like parseInt(2.5);

Comment: So do you have a decimal number stored in a string, or do you have an actual decimal number `nr=2.5` vs. `nr='2.5'`. The difference is important because of the solution, if it's a string I'd use a regular expression `/(\d+)(?:\.\d*)?/` (because the "numbers" can be very long and may have leading zeros), otherwise you can simple use `Math.floor()`.

Comment: *no matter how long the number is* there's limits to any computer as of how big numbers can be max. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ And no, any decimal number is **not an INT**.

Comment: So what is the answer 5545454454 or 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inbuilt Math functions like

```js
console.log(Math.trunc(2.51));
```